# Regex to replace specific characters in a string by location in the string?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to replace `Zone version:  2017102102` to `Zone version:  2018032501`.  The problem I have is the numerical portion is not consistent, but the string length and format is always `Zone Version:  NNNNNNNNNN`.  How does one say "replace characters 16-25 with 2018032501" in powershell?

I am familiar with basic -replace operations.  I just need to know how to tell the -replace operation to only change those particular characters in the string.

Comment: What do you have so far? You know that we do not write ready to use code on request, don't you? ;-)  You might re-review the following help topics: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To specify what to be replaced you can use regular expressions or substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to match 10 digits and replace them.

`"Zone version:  2017102102" -replace "(\d{10})",2018032501`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options available to do string operations in Powershell. For your task I see basically two slightly simple ways to achive what you need.

```
$OriginalString = 'Zone version:  2017102102'
$NewString = '2018032501'
```

Either with the `-replace` operator

```
$OriginalString -replace 'Zone\sversion:\s+\d{10}',"Zone version:  $NewString"
```

or with substrings.

```
$OriginalString.Substring(0,15) + $NewString
```